# Linux (Debian 8 Jessie) HRTimer - Kernel - Leap Seconds

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, cpu

ANSWER: VM Time Syncing is an art, I'm gonna count my blessings and use what already works for me.

This is why: ~qoute~
I've spent several years playing with synchronizing time between host and guest VMs, with and without NTP etc. - it's basically a black art and heavily dependent on hypervisor, both kernels, and a host of settings. We aren't going to sort it out in comments on SO, but if you have a known good configuration, I'd revert to that and change bit by bit until you know what breaks it.

– abligh

---

Edit:

The Percona information is for context, it is what I'm doing. But the issue IS realized as a leap second issue in Debian 8 kernel. Regarding the hrtimer (High-Res Timer). Mozilla's suggested fix is to reset the time using the "Date" function in linux, but attempting to set date tells me i dont have permission despite being root.

---

Information: The Inside Story of the Extra Second That Crashed the Web

http://wired.com/2012/07/leap-second-glitch-explained

---

Screenshots:

Recent Attempt: http://prnt.sc/c208x2

Top: http://prnt.sc/c202q9

Mysql ProcessList: http://prnt.sc/c20b4f

---

Context:

I've heard this had to do with a leap second issue, thing is, it doesn't fit my profile exactly.

I have several instances of debian linux in vm's on Proxmox.

2 Seperate Percona Galera-Mysql Clusters.

First cluster is original cluster which is in use, But it doesn't have this problem or has ever had. My new cluster setup does on all 3 nodes.

Ive tried applying several versions of the leap second fix

```
date
date -s "`date`"
date -s "`date`"
```

All ends in I don't have permission to do that except the first one, but I'm root!

And no work-y.

Many reboots.

Each instance except one slave have the same stats, I boosted one to test if it was a limited resource issue.

1 gig ram

1 3.6ghz cpu

The only other thing I can say is the problem starts AFTER I upload a backup database.

The database is one I already have in first cluster is around 5mb, and is mostly in relational table list style. These are not in use, not doing anything, many reboots later. I'm getting pretty stuck.

PS: Process List is empty. (1 for self look-up  and 2 sleep idles)

Comment: for more information: 
The Inside Story of the Extra Second That Crashed the Web
http://www.wired.com/2012/07/leap-second-glitch-explained/

Comment: can you post upper section of "top" command?, is there anything present in mysql log or in error log??

Comment: This is purely a time issue, it occurs in the hrtimer ( high res timer ) used in the linux kernel, I could post top, but its only like a couple items, primarily one service per VM, so mysql login bash etc.

Date setting using date function recieves permission denied, this is debian 8 Jessie

Comment: than please rename and retag your question since you are obvoiusly sure that its not percona related

Comment: As Adviced, Corrected.

Comment: A Recent Attempt: http://prnt.sc/c202q9

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am guessing that the problem here is that you are running on a VM (or even a container). Although you are root, you don't from the container / guest-OS have permission to change the time. That's because the time syncs from the host operating system, and clearly one can't change that.

If so, can you fix it in the host OS? Or do you not have access to that?

Also useful would be an

```
strace -f -s2048 -o/tmp/post-this-file date -s "`date`"
```

i.e. a trace of the system calls made by `date`.

The HiRes timer livelock you refer to was fixed upstream in [commit `id=6b43ae8a619d17c4935c3320d2ef9e92bdeed05d`](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=6b43ae8a619d17c4935c3320d2ef9e92bdeed05d).

The debian bug to incorporate them into the kernel seems to be [here](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=679882) and the fixes described [here](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=679882#82) (incorporated into Debian's 3.2.29-1 and 2.6.32-46 kernels). What kernel are you actually running (output of `uname -a` would be helpful)? This isn't always obvious, especially in a container environment.

Restarting Percona may fix the issue if you haven't tried that.

Post a little more about the environment and I might be able to be more help.

Comment: @iGNEOS - added some more information above just as you were commenting.

Comment: Excuse my ignorance, even as a programmer. But how do i apply the commit, i know compiling; i know git.

Comment: @iGNEOS unless you are recompiling the kernel, you don't. But I put the information in there (and the next para that follows) so you can tell whether the kernel you are running has the fix - as you may have a different problem. If you actually want to apply, get the source (preferably using `git clone` and `git checkout`, then create a branch `git checkout -b mybranch` and apply the patch with `git am`). However, it really will be so much easier to determine whether your kernel has the patch (it was fixed many years ago), and if not upgrade the kernel to a prebuilt one.

Comment: @iGNEOS I'm also intrigued as to why you can't set the date. I suspect virtualisation is at play, in which case it may be the *host* kernel that needs fixing.

Comment: 10-4 ill run the test and post results (ps i run the date function on root of the vms and it was successful, rebooting vm in question did not fix it, cant technically reboot root of vms without bringing down a real-time high-transactional live website.,like to avoid that

Comment: @iGNEOS do you know this is definitely related to a leap second issue? There are issues with guest/host VM time synchronization which could cause the same effect without a leap second (in essence if the parent VM resyncs via NTP and the child VMs use specific time synchronization techniques). Shouldn't happen with proxmox containers, but if using proxmox VMs with Qemu+KVM, please post the qemu command line, and your kernel command line if any for the guest.

Comment: Ok im at the point where i feel out of place, and on the deep end, i have been thinking about my situation. I have a similar scenario of running vms, with debian 7 and percona servers and no issues, they have more resources ( 4 cpu 7 gb ram) instead of my new ones which are debian 8, ( 1cpu 1+gb ram) im thinking of using the same architecture i used originally and work my way back to a clean slate and the servers i need. Thoughts?

Comment: if you have nothing further ill accept your answer.

Comment: @iGNEOS I've spent several years playing with synchronizing time between host and guest VMs, with and without NTP etc. - it's basically a black art and heavily dependent on hypervisor, both kernels, and a host of settings. We aren't going to sort it out in comments on SO, but if you have a known good configuration, I'd revert to that and change bit by bit until you know what breaks it.

Comment: Im gonna do just That I appreciate the advice (though im gonna attempt not to break it :P ) Thank you again.

Comment: @iGNEOS - ooh. One further thing you can consider: migrating the VM off the box and back again (possibly rebooting the host in between)